# File extension for Book App iPhone and Android

Tags: android, iphone, cordova

For the first time I am building a book app. I am developing the app so that you can pick from one - 5 books and buy the book as an in app purchase.  I am using phonegap to build the app.

My question is what file format do I need to use for the actual books for iPhone? and what file format do I need for Android?

I need to prepare the file of the actual book and I need to know what extension they should be in to properly function. thanks!

Comment: .pdf format would be nice, i think

Comment: epub scales better than pdf (pdf is more of a printing format)

Comment: could I use epub also for the android version?

Comment: it depends, if you want users to view and not download then you don't want PDF, because of file size, and copyrights issue, and PDF easy to pull from downloads folder in SD card.

Comment: I would like the end user to be able to download the book so they don't have to constantly fetch from the server each time they want to read the book.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any one out of .epub, .mobi or .pdf.

In .pdf files Adobe has addressed the  drawback of fixed screen size by adding a re-flow facility to its Acrobat Reader software. Most good PDF software now supports reflow so this limitation is one best left in the past.

Here are few links on same

[PDF](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/PDF)

[Comparison_of_e-book_formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_formats)

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into the open standards like epub or mobi. PDF I wouldn't recommend, because it's very static and doesn't scale well. (e.g. a page is a page, regardless of the screen size)